# <p:dataTable multiple selection mode. How to assign values immediately?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a list of items, the problem is that after selection "mngr" bean property "selectedItems" doesn't get assigned with these selected items.

```
<p:dataTable id="tbl" var="item" 
    value="#{mngr.itemsTableModel}" widgetVar="tbl"
    selectionMode="multiple" selection="#{mngr.selectedItems}">

    <p:column headerText="Name">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>  
    </p:column>  
</p:dataTable>

<p:commandButton value="Assign" process="tbl"/>
```

Selection fails even if "Assign" button is pressed and partial processing is completed.
Maybe there is ajax even for multiple selection?

Comment: To avoid the obvious, is the whole placed in a form and is the bean put in the right scope for the data it holds?

Comment: Yes, let's just assume that form has prependId="true"

Comment: Oh, by the way, then i press button to proccess datatable my "mngr" bean method "setItemsTableModel(List<Item> items)" gets empty list of items.

Comment: This is strange, the setter method behind `<p:dataTable value>` is never invoked by JSF itself. Also, the `List<Item>` type tells that this isn't a `DataModel` at all and thus also not a `SelectableDataModel` which is required when you use `selection` without `rowKey`. You should follow the examples at PrimeFaces showcase.